# Unique (constant) jenkins slave id?

Tags: jenkins

I am setting up integration tests on a Jenkins server with multiple slaves. Because I want to have parallel builds and therefore parallel tests running. This means that I need to have multiple databases (with connection details).

In order to set this up I provide a `-Djenkins=` parameter, but I need a (constant) unique id for each jenkins slave.

...does a parameter exist for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the available environment variables in a build step is NODE_NAME. See below the description:

```
NODE_NAME
    Name of the slave if the build is on a slave, or "master" if run on master
```

Comment: I was trying to google to figure out what "level" of uniqueness it gives and it appears to only give to node level, but what I actually need is executor level (multiple executors per node)...or have I got that wrong?

Comment: I've just seen where you got this, I can use a concatenation of  `NODE_NAME` and `EXECUTOR_NUMBER`

Comment: You might be able to use the port allocator Plugin. just define a few 'port numbers' which can be used to identify your different db profiles. Jenkins makes sure that only one process uses one port (read: db profile) at a time. That of course means that you don't know beforehand what db will be used for your test. https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Port+Allocator+Plugin